# Htaccess css localhost

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule "^bar/(.*)$" "bar.php?sef_link=$1"
```

my htaccess rule is work but css, images and js files does not load.

when i look into source code, css file redirect :

localhost/css/style.css

but my css path is : localhost/night-rock/css/style.css

how can i fix this problem ?

i tried to add "/" before call css path :

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

if i tried without "/" it search in:

```
http://localhost/night-rock/bar/css/style.css
```

Comment: remove the preceeding / in your html so it will be relative, ie : `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: @Pogrindis it tried it, but does not work.

Comment: What is the route 404 when you remove it ?

Comment: Try going up a directory before looking for the css directory: `<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: remove `bar/` from your `htaccess` or if this folder exists (/bar).. Then add `../css` to your `HTML`

Comment: yes it works, thanks. please write as a response to accept it

Comment: Guess @CaptainAdams could be named Captain Obvious too! `:P`

Comment: I'm still unsure if the folder `bar` actually exists though.. O_o (damn `foo`, `bar` ambiguity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove `bar/` from your `htaccess` file.

Or if this folder does exists (/bar)..

Then add `../css` to your HTML which will give it a relative path to the parent folder.